# Ruby selenium/capybara wait for element to go away

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec, kendo-ui, capybara

I know this isn't a unique problem but I have yet to find an actual solution... I have a page that has a spinner on it while it is loading. What I would like my ruby rspec to do is wait for the spinner to go away before it moves on...

I've already implemented a `wait_for_ajax` which helps but doesn't completely solve the issue:

```
def wait_for_ajax
  Timeout.timeout(Capybara.default_max_wait_time) do
    loop until page.evaluate_script('jQuery.active').zero?
  end
end
```

Given the spinner has a certain class (generated by Kendo), how can I wait for that element to go away? This is what I'm currently trying...

```
def wait_until_load
  Timeout.timeout(Capybara.default_max_wait_time) do
    loop until !find(".k-loading-color")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

99% of the time if you need `wait_for_ajax` you're doing something wrong.  In your current case you should just be doing

```
expect(page).to have_no_css('.k-loading-color')
```

which will wait up to `Capybara.default_max_wait_time` seconds for matching elements to disappear. If you need to allow longer than you have `Capybara.default_max_wait_time` set to you can override the maximum wait time like

```
expect(page).to have_no_css('.k-loading-color', wait: 10)
```

which will wait up to 10 seconds for any matching items to disappear

Comment: @Zack Upping your `default_max_wait_time` is fine, and on pretty much all of Capybara's finders/matchers/assertions you can override that default by passing the `:wait` option if you need for a specific thing.  The thing a lot of people fail to grab is that both `default_max_wait_time` and the `:wait` option specify maximum wait times so making it longer really doesn't slow anything down in most cases (other than failures)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using:

```
def wait_until_load
  Timeout.timeout(Capybara.default_max_wait_time) do
    loop until page.has_no_css?(".k-loading-color")
  end
end
```

Comment: has_no_css? already has waiting behavior and `Timeout.timeout` is actually a very dangerous method to use with programs involving network connections since it can leave the connection in a completely unknown state - explanation: https://medium.com/@adamhooper/in-ruby-dont-use-timeout-77d9d4e5a001

Answer (score 0):

If your current loop isn't working, I expect the spinner with class k-loading-color is remaining in the DOM but with the hidden property.

I'd try using the visible? method

```
def wait_until_load
  Timeout.timeout(Capybara.default_max_wait_time) do
    loop until !find(".k-loading-color").visible?
  end
end
```

Of course this will only work if

```
find(".k-loading-color").visible? == true
```

when the page first loads

Comment: By default `find` only finds visible elements so checking `visible?` immediately on an element returned from `find` is pointless.